# "More scientific" replacement for "Abstellgleis"

Tags: phrase-request, scientific-language, written-language

I'm looking for a more scientific word than "Abstellgleis" in the following context:

> Nach der Übergabe des Projektes an die Open-Source-Gemeinschaft scheint das Projekt auf dem Abstellgleis gelandet zu sein ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to express yourself in a "more scientific" way, the way to go would be to avoid "colourful metaphors" like "Abstellgleis". Instead, just describe what is happening:

> Nach der Übergabe des Projektes an die Open-Source-Gemeinschaft scheint keine weitere Entwicklung mehr daran stattzufinden ...

Of course, "Abstellgleis" might concretely refer to a multitude of things (for a full-fledged project, for instance, the focus would probably rather be on the lack of active community members in support forums), so the above is only an example.

Answer (score 6):

Here some examples. Hope one fits you:

**Nach der Übergabe des Projektes an die Open-Source-Gemeinschaft scheint das Projekt...**

... in Vergessenheit geraten zu sein.

... in den Hintergrund geraten zu sein.

... an Aktualität zu verlieren.

... an Wichtigkeit zu verlieren.

... kein Interesse mehr zu erzeugen.

Comment: I really like ... in den Hintergrund geraten zu sein. Thanks

Comment: ... in der Schublade verschwunden zu sein.

Comment: ... in der Versenkung verschwunden zu sein.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich finde, die beiden Optionen (insbesondere die mit der Schublade) klingen zu sehr danach, dass das Projekt gar nicht mehr sichtbar/auffindbar/zugreifbar ist, was bei brachliegenden Open-Source-Projekten meist nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: *[...] seine Bedeutung verloren zu haben.*

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the current status of the project, whether it is still going ahead or not, you could for example say

- wird das Projekt aktuell/derzeit nicht weiterverfolgt/weitergeführt/weiterbetreut
- wurde das Projekt vorläufig eingestellt/unterbrochen
- endete die/unsere Betreuung für das Projekt
- ist das Projekt momentan zum Stillstand gekommen
- befindet sich das Projekt nach derzeitigem Stand in der Endphase
- ist eine Fortsetzung des Projekts zum derzeitigen Zeitpunkt ungewiss

I would rather stay away from flowery terms as it comes across a bit biased.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

> Nach der Übergabe des Projektes an die Open-Source-Gemeinschaft scheint das Projekt 
>   **unbeachtet von der Gemeinschaft** zu sein ...

Answer (score 3):

Stagnieren ist ein hübsches Fremdwort für den Fall:

Nach der Übergabe des Projektes an die Open-Source-Gemeinschaft scheint es nun **zu stagnieren**.

Answer (score 2):

Auch:

> nicht weitergeführt / fortgeführt zu werden
>
> auf Eis zu liegen [ebenfalls zu bildhaft]
>
> scheint die Projektarbeit ins Stocken geraten zu sein
>
> wird das Projekt nicht mehr mit Nachdruck weiterverfolgt
>
> scheint man mit dem Vorhaben nicht weiterzukommen / nicht voranzukommen
>
> scheint es (mit dem Projekt) keinen Fortschritt zu geben
>
> macht die Sache keinen (rechten) Fortschritt mehr
>
> ist dort kein Fortschritt mehr zu verzeichnen
>
> tritt man dort auf der Stelle [bildhaft]
>
> ist es um das Projekt (auffällig) still geworden
>
> hört man davon nichts Neues mehr
>
> scheint die Weiterentwicklung zu stagnieren
>
> scheint man sich dort um das Vorhaben nicht sehr intensiv zu kümmern
>
> sind in der Sache / Angelegenheit keine Aktivitäten mehr / kaum noch Aktivitäten zu verzeichnen

usw.

Übrigens: Besser nicht zweimal das Wort 'Projekt' in demselben Satz.

Comment: Ich würde unterschiedliche Klammern für [Erklärungen] und mögliche (Zusatzfloskeln) verwenden, um diese unterscheiden zu können.

Comment: Good idea, done.